# Google Cloud messaging failure_count not working

Tags: python, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to pass wrong token to Google Cloud Messaging `MulticastMessage()`:

```py
async def sendMessageAsync(registration_tokens: list[str]):
    message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
        notification=messaging.Notification(body="Text"), tokens=registration_tokens
    )
    response: messaging.BatchResponse = messaging.send_multicast(message)
    print(response.failure_count)  # 0


@https_fn.on_request(
    region="europe-west3", cpu="gcf_gen1", memory=options.MemoryOption.MB_256
)
def sendMessage_http(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    asyncio.run(sendMessageAsync(["wrongToken"]))
    return https_fn.Response(f"Closed")
```

But as a result I get `failure_count` of zero.

What is wrong here?

The similar code works fine if I use Google Cloud Messaging `Message()` - it generates exception as expected.